# Does there exist books dealing with actual geometry of metric spaces?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

Most books / notes of Metric space I find is about defining convergence, limits, topology etc. However, a metric is not just that. When we put a metric on a set, then we implicitly give it a geometry. So, for example, it makes sense to talk about things like squares, circles etc.

Is there a book discussing about the various results of Geometry which arise when we give , for example, $\mathbb{R^2}$ a metric?

Note: I am taking the generalization of circle as set of points equidistant from a given point and a square about a point as a four sided polygon with equal side lengths (length being in sense of appropriate metric).

---

I found this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.4239.pdf) which seems somewhat close to what I want.

Comment: what you are thinking of is riemannian geometry, I'd suggest picking up a book on that. Something like Lee's book is very good, and talks about geomtric things such as curvature.

Comment: I have seen DG before. It is not about this as far as I understand. They use metric in a different sense than the one in metric space. @AareyanManzoor

Comment: Maybe the google search ["geometry of metric spaces" -measure](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22geometry+of+metric+spaces%22+-measure&filter=0)? (I removed "measure" from the search to avoid metric measure spaces.)

Comment: Does adding "-thing" remove anything with "thing" inside it's text? @DaveL.Renfro til

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom A riemannian metric also induces a metric on the whole manifold. Admittedly this is at the end just restricted to manifolds and maybe you want to study this in the more general sense.

Comment: Seems like you’re looking for the subject of “metric geometry”, these notes: https://anton-petrunin.github.io/metric-geometry/tex/lectures.pdf by Anton Petrunin seem like a good place to start.

Comment: *Does adding "-thing" remove anything with "thing" inside it's text?* -- Yes. See [this web page](https://ahrefs.com/blog/google-advanced-search-operators/).

Answer (score 1):

> When we put a metric on a set, then we implicitly give it a geometry. So, for example, it makes sense to talk about things like squares, circles etc.

Unfortunately no it doesn't. A metric does not induce a geometry.

All you have with a metric is that the metric between two points is zero if and only if the two points are identical, otherwise the metric is always positive, the metric between a and b is the same as between b and a, and the distance between a and c is less than or equal to the sum of the distances between a and b plus b and c.

You cannot define a square, or a right angle or any other kind of angle using just that definition. The only thing which you can define is a "circle", as in a set of points which are equidistant from one point.

> I found this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.4239.pdf) which seems somewhat close to what I want.

OK but you cannot define "perpendicular" using a metric alone. It doesn't allow for that. But a metric space with an inner product, which is called a Hilbert space, has a geometry, and you can define perpendicular lines, squares, etc.

Comment: So, do you have any book recommendation which studies Geometry in the context of Hilbert spaces?